# Integrate websockets with apache

Tags: node.js, apache, cakephp, websocket, port

I would like to add a some real time data updates using push to an existing CakePHP application. It seems to me that websockets are the best way to do so and from what I've read, the easiest way to start using websockets is with node.js. Now the issue I have is that my application server is very very limited portwise and there is virtually no way to change that.

I have apache currently running on *:80 and *:443 and sslh listening on port *:4433. Requests from the outside are sent to my server on :4433 and sslh takes care of handling ssh and https traffic, however on the inside, all my clients machines are using :443 directly. I could potentially open more ports for inside clients, but from outside, there is currently no way to do this. Most of my clients connect from the inside network, but more and more are using the application from outside too.

Note that port 80 is only used to redirect users entering http://example.com to https://example.com as all my services are encrypted. So if node.js was able to to send every http request to https and use port 80 for secure websockets, this would work too!

My question: Is it possible to run Apache and Websockets (probably in the form of Node.js) on the same port, and have either Node.js working as a proxy for Apache or Apache working as a proxy for Node.js?